# Accessing data from backend throws error saying data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting some information from my backend server that I'm successfully rendering on my react app, but there is some values that I need to calculate and get.

I'm getting a state `{games.prices.price}` that will actually not work but no errors, but if I try something like `{game.prices[0].price}` I'm getting an errors or `{game.prices[0].price[0]}` that says price is undefined.

How can I actually get lowest price from that json?

This is how json response looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "panelgameid": 71,
        "name": "Counter-Strike 1.6",
        "active": 1,
        "minslots": 12,
        "maxslots": 32,
        "slotincreament": 2,
        "order": 1,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "gameid": 1,
                "location": "USA",
                "price": 0.6
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "gameid": 1,
                "location": "Germany",
                "price": 0.4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is my code:

```
class GameSlider extends Component {
  state = {
    games: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/games").then(res => {
      this.setState({
        games: res.data,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { games } = this.state;
    const gamesList = games.length ? (
      games.map(games => (
        <div>
          <div className="home-games">
            <div
              src=""
              className="img"
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sr/c/ce/Counter-Strike_Global_Offensive.jpg)`,
              }}
              alt="..."
            />
            <div className="price">
              Slot price
              <p>{games.prices.price}</p>
            </div>
            <span className="title">{games.name}</span>
            <div className="features">
              <Col span={24} className="feature">
                <Icon type="lock" /> Up to {games.maxslots} slots
              </Col>
            </div>

            <Button
              className="comet-buy-button"
              style={{ background: "rgb(241,89,89)", borderRadius: "20px" }}
            >
              BUY NOW!
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))
    ) : (
      <div>
        <h1>Nothing to show</h1>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="home-page-slider">
        <Slider {...settings} arrows={false}>
          {gamesList}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I'm successfully getting every information except price, I need to get in this example price of Germany, because it's lower price.

I have deleted settings for slider because it's working fine.

Comment: i guess that you need to resolve that response first: `axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/games')
        .then(res => {
            res.json().then(result => { this.setState({
                games: result.data
            })})
        })`

Comment: @messerbill axios takes care of this already.

Comment: _"I'm getting an errors"_ What's the error?

Comment: It's working now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the errors are a result of typing `game` instead of `games`. `{games.prices[0].price}` should work. However, in order to get the *lowest* price, your array needs to be sorted. As per Ali Raza's answer below, something like:

```js
Math.min(games.prices.map(el => el.price))
```

is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.min with spread operator to iterate and then map.

```
 let pricesState = Math.min(...state.prices.map(el => el.price));
```

Comment: So I have to add this after render() or before? Because when I tried this and change <p>{pricesState}</p> it's not working.

Comment: You can add this after render method, second " const { games } = this.state;" Should be this.state.games.